# How to ssh into a LXD guest?

Tags: permissions, ssh, kvm-virtualization, lxd

I have a **host** machine (KVM with Kubuntu 18.04) with a LXD **guest** (based on ubuntu18.04 image).

I can ssh from guest to host.

But trying to ssh from host to guest gives an

> Permission denied (publickey)

error

Step to reproduce:

- lxc exec into the guest
- exec login with ubuntu user (to avoid root permissions problems)
- ssh to host - **SUCCESS**
- exit form user ubuntu - exit from guest
- from host ssh into ubuntu@guest - **ERROR**

What I'm doing wrong?

Below the complete session transcript

```
sysop@kvmneo4j:~$ lxc list
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|   NAME   |  STATE  |       IPV4        | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| base1804 | RUNNING | 10.0.0.205 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------------+-----------+
sysop@kvmneo4j:~$ lxc exec base1804 bash
root@base1804:~# exec login ubuntu
Password: 
Last login: Wed Jan  2 18:58:10 UTC 2019 on UNKNOWN
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

System information as of Wed Jan  2 19:02:28 UTC 2019

System load:    1.69      Processes:           22
Usage of /home: unknown   Users logged in:     0
Memory usage:   1%        IP address for eth0: 10.0.0.205
Swap usage:     0%


Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings


To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubuntu@base1804:~$ ssh sysop@10.0.0.1
sysop@10.0.0.1's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


* Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
- Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
    https://ubuntu.com/livepatch
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Last login: Wed Jan  2 19:58:42 2019 from 10.0.0.205
sysop@kvmneo4j:~$ logout
Connection to 10.0.0.1 closed.
ubuntu@base1804:~$ logout
sysop@kvmneo4j:~$ ssh -v ubuntu@10.0.0.205
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.205 [10.0.0.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.0.205:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:i0Ezo01qJyhIue4PIRobOw/qKuvDW/7OJZzgB0X5jGM
debug1: Host '10.0.0.205' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sysop/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EfYKpv5N+M8YBgCFjjy3P9M0jYt7DObq9ApoZ0G8qL4 /home/sysop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysop/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@10.0.0.205: Permission denied (publickey).
sysop@kvmneo4j:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all Ubuntu `lxd` images for containers are set up with `PasswordAuthentication no` in their SSH configuration.

You need to go into the container directly and edit the config as `root`.

(1) `lxc shell CONTAINER-NAME` will drop you to a `root` shell.

(2) `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` will open the `nano` text editor to that file.

(3) Find the line `PasswordAuthentication no` and set it to `yes`.

(4) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the file.

(5) Restart the SSH service with `systemctl restart ssh`. (if this says you don't have permissions, prepend `sudo` to the command)

You should now be able to SSH into the container from the host system.

Comment: Thanks it worked. BTW what is the recommended method to interact by script with an LXD container? I mean rcp to transer files or something similar

Comment: The standard way you would transfer data between host and container would be `scp` or `rsync` - but you have to either use SSH keys or do these steps to enable password authentication.  Treat the container as its own OS whne you consider file transfers to/from it

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` before `systemctl restart ssh` in a **root** shell.

Answer (score 7):

A public key can be used for authentication.

1. add public key to authorized keys on the container:

```
cat <public_key_file_on_host> | lxc exec <container> -- sh -c "cat >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

2. restart the ssh daemon:

```
lxc exec <container> -- systemctl restart ssh
```

3. ssh into the container as ubuntu

```
ssh ubuntu@<container_ip>
```

Notes:

- Example `<public_key_file_on_host>`: `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (or generate a new one with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`)
- `<container_ip>` can be obtained with `lxc list`
- To use container names directly instead of IPs, try

  1. `` sudo systemd-resolve --interface=lxdbr0 --set-dns=`ip -f inet addr show dev lxdbr0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'` --set-domain=lxd ``
  2. `ssh ubuntu@<container>.lxd`

Answer (score 0):

Try from the guest:

```
ssh -A host
```

then from the host:

```
ssh final-destination
```

The "-A" forwards your agent from the guest to the host.

Comment: This won't work because of the container defaults which forbid password authentication.